# How to sum a list that contains letters by changing certain letters in a list with integers?

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, blackjack

Just started learning Python and I am trying to create a blackjack game. I want to find the sum of the card values in a player's hand. My approach was to change the letters "J", "Q","K" into values of 10 and change "A" to value of 11. I have defined the class Card but when I run the code, I get an error saying "type object 'Card' has no attribute 'value'"

```
import random


DEFAULT_SUITS = ("Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds","Spades")
DEFAULT_VALUES = ("A",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"J","Q","K")


class Card():
    def __init__ (self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
    
    def show(self):
        print(self.value, self.suit)

  
class Shoes():
    def __init__(self, decks, suits=DEFAULT_SUITS, values=DEFAULT_VALUES):
        self.cards = []
        for deck in range(decks):
            for suit in suits:
                for value in values:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit,value))
        random.shuffle(self.cards) 
        
    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()
    
    def drawcard(self):
        return self.cards.pop()
    
          
class Player():
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []
    
    def drawcard(self, shoes):
        self.hand.append(shoes.drawcard())
        return self
    
    def totalvalue(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            if Card.value == "J":
                self.hand = [10 if card=="J" else card for card in cards]
            if Card.value == "Q":
                self.hand = [10 if card=="Q" else card for card in cards]
            if Card.value == "K":
                self.hand = [10 if card=="K" else card for card in cards]
            if Card.value == "A":
                self.hand = [11 if card=="A" else card for card in cards]    
        self.totalvalue = sum(self.hand(Card.value))
    
    def showhand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()
            
shoe = Shoes(int(input("Enter the number of deck used in a shoes: ")))

bob = Player("bob")
bob.drawcard(shoe)
bob.showhand()
bob.totalvalue()
```

How can I change the values "J","Q","K","A" in hand and sum it up to get the total value?

Comment: Can you share how you run the code?

Comment: Added with the execution parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there is some confusion in using the list of Cards. Here what you should be doing

```
def totalvalue(self):
    total = 0
    for card in self.hand:
        if card.value in ["J", "Q", "K"]:
            total = total + 10
        elif card.value == "A":
            total = total + 11
        else:
            total = total + card.value
        
    self.totalvalue = total
```

Code can be further simplified using the list comprehension as follows

```
def totalvalue(self):
    return  sum([10 if card.value in ['J', 'Q', 'K'] else 11 if card.value == 'A' else card.value for  card in self.hand])
```

Comment: Please ask the question

Comment: Thank you so much, this was what I was trying to solve! I was wondering if I can ask one more question regarding the card.value in ["j","q","K"] part. Is card.value in ["j","q","k"] using the class Card() or is it taking the individual card in self.hand and pulling in only the value?

Comment: All the elements of self.hand list are instances of Card class and is taking individual card in the hand and getting it's value

Comment: Gotcha, so currently the elements in list self.card is currently structured as "value" + "suits not "value + suits"?

Answer (score 1):

you have used Card.value, where Card is a class instace, just change Card to card in totalvalue function.

and next thing, i will suggest to make a dictionary;
and take every value from that even numbers too.

```
dict = {'A':1, '2':2,.......}
```

and so on, like this

```
def totalvalue(self):
   self.totalvalue =0;
   dict = {'A':1, '2':2,.......};
       for card in self.hand:
            self.totalvalue = self.totalvalue +dict[card.value]
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to keep the structure as is rather than using a dictionary?

Comment: Yeah I think adding dictionary is adding more code than needed. Checkout the answer below from me